# Actionabar issues coming from full screen

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I got a full screen activity that leads to an activity with an action bar. When the scond activity loads, the actionbar is half hidden by the title menu.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

**EDIT:** as seen below, the title bar hides some of the action bar.
[image: The title bar hides some of the action bar]

Comment: @Lokesh added a screenshot demonstrating what I'm talking about. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 ) You have to keep same theme for all activity ,put actionbar activity them in application tag in manifest file

2) If you want to use full screen activity then getSupportActionBar().hide(); If you have Simle activity and Actionbar activity then while launching simple Actionbar activity to Simple activity creates problem.

Comment: The first activity's theme is quite different than the current one (where the action bar's hidden), is there any way around it?

Comment: I had encounter with same problem , I have solved the issue with keeping same Theme, till date not found any other solution .

Answer (score 0):

check your activity deceleration in the manifest file. Declarer your activity like this.

```
 <activity 
        android:name="com.android.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
 </activity>
```